# selenium try and catch

Tags: java, selenium, automation

```
package com.OSCom.CommonMethods;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class CommonMethods {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public CommonMethods(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    public void clickElement(WebElement slocator)
    {
        try
        {
            slocator.click();
            System.out.println(slocator+" clicked");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(slocator+ " NOT clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

So I have this simple method that would click on a link in selenium. If I just do:

```
slocator.click();
```

then everything runs fine. However, when I put them in the try and catch block, it gives me this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=37.0.2062.120)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 30.12 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'
System info: host: 'Khoi-PC', ip: '192.168.1.133', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Session ID: 9b7e97ea09696dfc78ade8e6503a548a
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\Khoi\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6056_19855}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=37.0.2062.120, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:401)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:34)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.OSCom.CommonMethods.CommonMethods.clickElement(CommonMethods.java:30)
    at com.OSCom.page.HomePage.clickLogIn(HomePage.java:26)
    at com.OSCom.tests.LogInTest.logInTest(LogInTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Sorry I will post all the code. I was afraid to cause confusion. This is the class that will call CommonMethods:

```
package com.OSCom.page;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;

import com.OSCom.CommonMethods.CommonMethods;

public class HomePage {
    private WebDriver driver;
    CommonMethods CM;

    @FindBy(how=How.LINK_TEXT, using = "log yourself in")
    private WebElement logIn; 

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void clickLogIn() throws InterruptedException
    {
        CM = new CommonMethods(driver);

        CM.clickElement(logIn);
    }
}
```

This is my test class running with testNg

```
package com.OSCom.tests;

import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.OSCom.CommonMethods.CommonMethods;
import com.OSCom.page.HomePage;
import com.OSCom.page.SignInPage;

public class LogInTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    CommonMethods CM;
    public String URLName = "link here";
    private String dataFilePath = "S:\\Selenium\\Assignment\\TestData.xls";
    private String[][] data;
    private int dataRow = 2;
    private int dataCol = 2;

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
    public void setUp()
    {
        CM = new CommonMethods(driver);
        driver=CM.openBrower("Chrome");
        CM.navigateURL(URLName);
    }

    @Test
    public void logInTest() throws InterruptedException, BiffException, IOException
    {
        HomePage homepage = new HomePage(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, homepage);
        homepage.clickLogIn();

        data = CM.readExcel(dataRow, dataCol, dataFilePath);

        SignInPage signIn = PageFactory.initElements(driver, SignInPage.class);
        signIn.enterInfo(data[1][0],data[1][1]);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void done()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: can you pls post the part where `clickElement` mehtod is invoked

Comment: Please indicate which line this is: `at com.OSCom.CommonMethods.CommonMethods.clickElement(CommonMethods.java:30)`

Comment: The part that confuses me is when you instatiate CommonMethods you set the driver but you dont use it to do your click. I guess id assume thats your issue with finding the element. driver.find(slocator).click